# Is it possible to connect Dialogflow with data on a FTP server?

Tags: ftp, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm constructing a chatbot in the default section of Dialogflow. For this chatbot i'm wondering if it's possible to connect the chatbot with a Filezilla FTP server.

The chatbot should be able to communicate with the data on the server.

note: the file on the server is a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-into Dialogflow that will talk to the FTP server, fetch the file and data, and respond appropriately.

However...

You can certainly write a [fulfillment webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) that takes the Intent and parameters that are matched from Dialogflow, make the connection to the FTP server, get the JSON file, and use all of this to create a response to the user however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible , Dialogflow is fully based on json but you have to understand that json perfectly because in dialogflow there are multiple integration possible so you have to be sure on which integration do you want to work and follow that json structure in your code.